# Given $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1/n} = b$ with $b\in(0,1)$, prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$ and $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=1} a_n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Given that $(a_n)$ is a real sequence such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n|^{1/n} = b$ with $b\in(0,1)$, prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = 0$ and $\displaystyle\sum^\infty_{n=1} a_n$ converges.

I think that I've got the first part; the given statement implies that $\lim_{n\to\infty} |a_n| = b^n=0$  since $b^n=0$ as $n\to\infty$.I've already proven that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_n| = 0$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$ in another exercise using the definition of convergence of sequences.

For the second statement I'm not sure how to show the series converges. The only tests I have learnt so far are D'Alambert's Ratio Test (which I don't think I can use here without an explicit definition for $a_n$) and the comparison test, but I'm not sure what I can compare with to show that it does converge.

Comment: There are a few ways to see the first part, but it's invalid to take the $n$th power of both sides when $n$ is taken as a limit.

Comment: For the second part (and the first, obviously), notice that $|a_n|<c^n$ for some $0<c<1$ and sufficiently large $n$.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use the root test that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges if $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|a_n|^{1/n}=b$
for $0<b<1$. Moreover, if $b$ is less than one then $b^n$ tends to $0$.

You can read more in this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test).

Comment: This is not the ratio test, that's called root test.

Comment: sorry written fastly i made mistake

Comment: @Antarjoy I edit for you, please approve